# Triple DES encryption string generates "\n"

Tags: java, android, encryption, des

While encrypting a string, it generates `'\n'` at end of the string.

This is how I'm doing encryption

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {
        byte[] tdesKeyData = Consts.getSecretKey().getBytes();
        byte[] myIV = Consts.getInitializationVector().getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(tdesKeyData, "DES");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(myIV);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);

        byte[] plainTextBytes = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
        byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.encode(buf, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String base64EncryptedString = new String(base64Bytes);
        return base64EncryptedString;
    }
```

Please, somebody, guide me, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Once you solve your error, just one advice: Don't use DES, it's outdated nowadays. Use something like AES.

Comment: If `Base64.DEFAULT` is selected as the 2nd parameter in `Base64#encode`, the result contains line breaks. With [`Base64.NO_WRAP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#NO_WRAP) the result has no line breaks.

Comment: yes Just saw in documentation  just now https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html and fixed  @Topaco Yes ur right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Base64.NO_WRAP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

> Encoder flag bit to omit all line terminators (i.e., the output will be on one long line).